# Runtime return (lldb) when implement class in xcode 6

Tags: ios, function, class, xcode6, lldb

In Operation.h

```
@interface Operation : NSObject
-(float)addition:(float)number1 plusWith:(float)number2;
@end
```

In Operation.m

```
#import "Operation.h"
@implementation Operation
-(float)addition:(float)number1 plusWith:(float)number2 {
    return number1 + number2;
}
@end
```

In ViewController.m

```
#import "Operation.h"
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
Operation *Math = [[Operation alloc] init];
    float doPlus = [Math addition:3.0 plusWith:4.0];
    NSLog(@"%f + %f = %f",3.0,4.0,doPlus);
}
```

Why runtime just return (lldb) ? Where is my error ? 
My debug area :
[image]

Comment: I am getting the output |  3.000000 + 4.000000 = 7.000000

Comment: When it stops at (lldb) type the command 'bt' and paste what it prints into your question.

Comment: Both `thread info` and `bt` can be illuminating.

Comment: @AshishKakkad - thanks your mention but that's amazing !

Comment: @PhillipMills and Rob : Thank you for your reply ! I have added my debug area image into question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error in your code. The reason your code is stopping is that you have put a breakpoint at this line:

```
return number1 + number2;
```

A breakpoint means "stop here". The debugger is stopping there because that is what your breakpoint tells it to do.

So you can either remove the breakpoint or else, when the debugger stops at the breakpoint, you can tell it to resume running from that point.

Comment: Here's my online discussion of breakpoints and the Xcode debugger: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch09.html#_the_xcode_debugger